# Sensible notion of closure of topological subspace under paths

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Let $X$ be a topological space, $Y \subseteq X$. If $X$ is a metric space, then the closure of $\bar{Y}$ is the set of limit points of sequences in $Y$. I thought of the following generalisation (now for $X$ arbitrary again). Define the *path-closure* of $Y$ in $X$ to be:

$$Y^P = \bigcup_S \gamma([0,1]) = \bigcup_S \gamma(1)$$

where $S$ = $\{ \gamma:[0,1] \to X : \gamma([0,1)) \subseteq Y \}$. Thus, $Y^P$ is the set of limit points of "paths in $Y$". It can be shown that $Y \subseteq Y^P \subseteq \bar{Y}$.

This notion of closure is much more restrictive, so naturally, it is also much weaker. It turns out that path-closure is not idempotent i.e. we do not necessarily have $(Y^P)^P = Y^P$.

Here is an example. Let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$. I will use some unusual notation: if $x \in \mathbb{R}, I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, let $(x,I)$ be the obvious interval in $\mathbb{R}^2$. (Similarly for $(I,y)$.) Consider:

$$Y = \Bigg(\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1)} \Big(x,[-1,0)\Big) \Bigg)  \cup \Bigg(\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1)} \Big(x,(0,1]\Big) \Bigg)$$

(Double-sided comb with no shaft and dense/co-dense set of teeth on either side.)

Then,

$$Y^P = \Bigg(\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1)} \Big(x,[-1,0]\Big) \Bigg)  \cup \Bigg(\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1)} \Big(x,[0,1]\Big) \Bigg)$$

but:

$$(Y^P)^P = \Bigg(\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]} \Big(x,[-1,0]\Big) \Bigg)  \cup \Bigg(\bigcup_{x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]} \Big(x,[0,1]\Big) \Bigg)$$

Note that $(1,0) \in (Y^P)^P \setminus Y^P$. Hence, this concept does not currently satisfy what we would expect from a notion of closure.

---

Let $Y^{P^2}$ denote $(Y^P)^P$. We will also write $Y^{P^n}$ for $n$ arbitrary.

**Question**: Let the *full path-closure* of a subspace $Y$ be $\bigcup_n Y^{P^n}$. Is this operation idempotent on $\mathcal{P}(X)$?

Perhaps this is a solution, but the definition of $Y^{P^n}$ is quite unpleasant to deal with.

**Question**: Is there a better definition of the notion of path-closure? Is this just completely useless?

Comment: How are you planning to use it? I see only trouble coming from this construction.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I have no use for it yet. It seems like a natural extension, but it has no motivation otherwise. After thinking of it, I was curious if the set of all path-closures can be the closed sets of a well-defined topology, but this fails for a few reasons. What (other) trouble do you see?

Comment: Actually, you did what the early explorers typically do: you've tried a way that looked promising and found it unpleasant. You know, North America could have been populated by the descendants of Vikings, but something went wrong. For similar reasons, we hear a lot about closures, but hardly anything at all about path-closures.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I tend to give up rather easily. If I had been a Viking landing in the most pristine, fecund land on Earth, I still might have turned back because founding a civilisation is a lot of effort. I wondered if maybe this one shouldn't be given up on, bleak though the outlook was. I think the comb I came up with is pretty cool, though. One can see (with not too much effort) that it could be generalised so that $Y^{P^{n-1}} \neq Y^{P^n}$. If anyone reads this, can you find a space with $Y \neq Y^P \neq Y^{P^2} \neq \cdots$?

Comment: I guess we may take your construction to 3D and beyond, and thus obtain sets which need arbitrarily many steps of path-closure. I have strong doubts about founding a civilisation on this shore, though. Had it been suitable, it would have already been done.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yes, arbitrarily many steps is what I already observed, no? Indeed, we can do this with similar constructions in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. I am curious if there is a space which, no matter how many path-closures we apply, the sequence never stabilises.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Ah, I just answered my own question actually. Take the disjoint union of all of the constructions for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ as a subspace of $\sqcup_n \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Quite a boring solution, actually.